# Please Checkout Flex in Navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a clone of amazon website. In the navbar "display: flex; " is not working. I an new to web development. Please help me! Please read the the code and tell me the about the error.

I tried using this command in index.html.  Make a folder name img within the folder where you have your html file and change the src path to

The logo appears but flex is not working.

```
.navbar{
  display : flex}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  border: border-box;
}

.navbar {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
}

.nav-logo {
  height: 50px;
  width: 113;
}

.logo {
  height: 50px;
  width: 113;
  background-image: url("amazon_logo.png");
  background-repeat: cover;
}

.boder {
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}

.boder.hover {
  border: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-iecdLmaskl7CVkqkXNQ/ZH/XLlvWZOJyj7Yy7tcenmpD1ypASozpmT/E0iPtmFIB46ZmdtAc9eNBvH0H/ZpiBw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
  <!-- link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" -->
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="navbar">
      <div class="nav-logo border">
        <div class="logo">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="nav-address">
      <p>Deliver To</p>
      <div class="add-icon"></div>
      <i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i>
      <p>India</p>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: `width: 113;` you should be adding in the size like you do with height. Probably `px`. Also `border` is spelled wrong in your CSS. Also you may have to adjust the path to your logo image file depending on where it is in your folder structure. Use the network tab in your dev console to help you.

Comment: The logo appears but flex is not working

Comment: What are you expecting `flex` to do here that it's not doing?

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question.

Answer (score 0):

You are having some typos in your code, which causes issues.

1.`.boder` -> `.border`
2. In the `.nav-logo` and `.logo` classes, specify the units for `width` property such as `px`

With these corrections `flex` should work and the logo should display within the navbar.

Note that: With only one child within the navbar the property `flex` doesn't make any big sense, add some nav links or menu items to see the real flex property effect.

Comment: Respected sir, are you saying to add width=113px in in .nav-logo and .logo class in index.html file. In style.css these attributes are already added to respective classes

Comment: You were right sir ! The problem is resolved. I tried this....... With only one child within the navbar the property flex doesn't make any big sense, add some nav links or menu items to see the real flex property effect.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that in both .logo class and .nav-logo class you typed a width value without a unit for them like (px, rem, vw, etc.), also You have to set some attriubutes for the background logo of .logo class like background position, background-size, and also style.css has a typo in .border class

Below Code I provided would work for you

```css
* {
            margin: 0;
            font-family: Arial;
            border: border-box;
        }

        .navbar {
            height: 60px;
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
            display: flex;
        }

        .nav-logo {
            height: 50px;
            width: 113px;

        }

        .logo {
            height: 50px;
            width: 113px;
            background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/a/a9/Amazon_logo.svg/2560px-Amazon_logo.svg.png");
            background-repeat: cover;
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: contain;
        }

        .border {
            border: 2px solid transparent;

        }

        .border.hover {
            border: 2px solid white;
        }
```

```html
<header>
        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="nav-logo border">
                <div class="logo">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-address">
            <p>Deliver To</p>
            <div class="add-icon"></div>
            <i class="fa-solid fa-location-dot"></i>
            <p>India</p>
        </div>
    </header>
```